# Magento2 Paypal Express checkout stop auto create invoice

Tags: magento2, invoice, paypal-express

i have setup **Paypal Express Checkout** in my magento2 website,
when user place the order, **invoice** is **automatically create**,
i want to stop that auto create invoice using **custom code**

how i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to disable auto invoice invoice programatically then plese follow below steps

1. In your custom module create di.xml file and add preference

```html
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Processor" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Express\Processor"/>
```

2. Create new file at Vendor\Module\Model\Express\ with Processor.php and add below code:

```html
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Express;

use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderPaymentInterface;

class Processor extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Processor
{
    const PAYMENT_METHOD_PAYPAL_EXPRESS = "paypal_express";
    /**
     * Process capture operation
     *
     * @param OrderPaymentInterface $payment
     * @param InvoiceInterface $invoice
     * @return OrderPaymentInterface|Payment
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function capture(OrderPaymentInterface $payment, $invoice)
    {
        if ($payment->getMethodInstance()
            ->getCode() != self::PAYMENT_METHOD_PAYPAL_EXPRESS)
        {
            return $this
                ->captureOperation
                ->capture($payment, $invoice);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Registers capture notification.
     *
     * @param OrderPaymentInterface $payment
     * @param string|float $amount
     * @param bool|int $skipFraudDetection
     * @return OrderPaymentInterface
     */
    public function registerCaptureNotification(OrderPaymentInterface $payment, $amount, $skipFraudDetection = false)
    {
        if ($payment->getMethodInstance()
            ->getCode() != self::PAYMENT_METHOD_PAYPAL_EXPRESS)
        {
            return $this
                ->registerCaptureNotification
                ->registerCaptureNotification($payment, $amount, $skipFraudDetection);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: It's for Magento 2X